Raspberry Pi 3, 4 work fine with Blinkt led lights, but same software does not work with Pi 5
I have a Docker container that will display the CPU load for the Kubernetes cluster on the blinkt LED if they are present for that node. It works fine on a Pi 3B and 4 but I just got some Pi 5's and the container is failing with this error on start:
Traceback (most recent call last):File "//./cpuload.py", line 33, in <module>blinkt.show()File     "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/blinkt.py", line 76, in showGPIO.setup(DAT, GPIO.OUT)RuntimeError:  Mmap of GPIO registers failed

Here is the Docker file that I am using and works fine on the Pi 4 for example:
FROM balenalib/raspberrypi4-64-debian-node

RUN apt-get update -qy && apt-get install -qy \
    gcc \ 
    python3-dev \
    pip \
    python3 \
    python3-rpi.gpio

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip install psutil blinkt 

COPY src/ .

CMD [ "python3", "./cpuload.py" ]

Here is the python code for the cpuload.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import os.path
import signal
from os import path
from sys import exit

def sigterm_handler( _signo, _stak_frame ):
  for x in range(blinkt.NUM_PIXELS):
    blinkt.set_pixel(x, 0, 0, 0)
  sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)

try:
    import psutil
except ImportError:
    exit("This script requires the psutil module\nInstall with: sudo pip install psutil")

try:
  import blinkt
except ImportError:
  exit("This script requires the blinkt module\nInstall with: sudo pip install blinkt")

blinkt.set_clear_on_exit()
blinkt.set_brightness(0.2)

while True:
    for x in range(blinkt.NUM_PIXELS):
        blinkt.set_pixel(x, 0, 0, 0)

    blinkt.show()
    if path.exists("/home/pi/.BLINK"):
        v = psutil.cpu_percent() / 100.0
        if v > 0.11 or (v > 0 and v < 0.11):
            blinkt.set_brightness(0.1)
            blinkt.set_pixel(0, 0, 128, 0)
        if v > 0.22 or (v > 0.11 and v < 0.22):
            blinkt.set_brightness(0.2)
            blinkt.set_pixel(1, 0, 128, 0)
        if v > 0.33 or (v > 0.22 and v < 0.33):
            blinkt.set_brightness(0.3)
            blinkt.set_pixel(2, 0, 128, 0)
        if v > 0.44 or (v > 0.33 and v < 0.44):
            blinkt.set_brightness(0.4)
            blinkt.set_pixel(3, 255, 215, 0)
        if v > 0.55 or (v > 0.44 and v < 0.55):
            blinkt.set_brightness(0.5)
            blinkt.set_pixel(4, 255, 215, 0)
        if v > 0.66 or (v > 0.55 and v < 0.66):
            blinkt.set_brightness(0.6)
            blinkt.set_pixel(5, 255, 215, 0)
        if v > 0.77 or (v > 0.66 and v < 0.77):
            blinkt.set_brightness(0.7)
            blinkt.set_pixel(6, 255, 0, 0)
        if v > 0.88:
            blinkt.set_brightness(0.8)
            blinkt.set_pixel(7, 255, 0, 0)
        blinkt.show()
        time.sleep(0.01)

I understand from reading some posts that somethings have changed on the GPIO but not entirely sure how to fix it, another Python GPIO library?
I have tried it with Pi 3 and Pi 4 and work fine. Above is the error message on the Pi 5 from the Docker container.

Have you tried your setup with the simple blinkt demo program at https://pinout.xyz/pinout/blinkt?

Yes, that example and others yields the same error I posted above only on the pi 5 not pi 4

This error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "//./test.py", line 10, in 
show()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/blinkt.py", line 76, in show
GPIO.setup(DAT, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: Mmap of GPIO registers failed

The other difference between the pi 3 and 4 is the pi 5's are running Bookworm:  Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)   6.6.20+rpt-rpi-2712

The fact that you get the same error with the demo program is very useful. It gets rid of a mass of possibilites. Why not rewrite your question giving just the code from the demo program, and quoting the error message that you get from it.

I get the following error without the POE hat on the pi 5 which is slightly different than the above:       File "//./pingnode.py", line 33, in 
blinkt.show()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/blinkt.py", line 76, in show
GPIO.setup(DAT, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: Cannot determine SOC peripheral base address
